# Apex Test Class - How to set a rollup count field in a test class

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Trying to set a value for a roll up summary field in the test class to improve code coverage. How do I do it?

```
public class clsPreferredIASetExt {

    List<PreferredIA__c> preferredias;
    public static PreferredIA__c[]  tobeClosed = new PreferredIA__c[0];
    public static PreferredIA__c[] newPreIAs = new PreferredIA__c[0];
    public static PreferredIA__c loopadd;
    public static PreferredContact__c[] contactlists = new PreferredContact__c[0];
    public static Account[] InvoicedAccounts = new Account[0];
    public static PreferredIA__c[] monkey;

    public clspreferrediaSetExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        preferredias = (List<PreferredIA__c>) controller.getSelected();
    }

    public void getInitCloseInv() {
        tobeclosed = [select id, Account__c, Account__r.id, Account__r.Name,
                             Account__r.AccountNumber, Specialist__c, 
                             PreferredInvoice__c, Status__c
                        from PreferredIA__c where Status__c = 'Invoiced' limit 150];

        list<string> testme = new list<string>{};
        for(PreferredIA__c a:tobeclosed) {
            testme.add(a.Account__r.id);    
        }

        InvoicedAccounts = [select  id, EligibleIAs__c, PreferredOverride__c,   
                                    Preferred_Territory__r.rep__c, LastSurveyDate__c,
                                    InitialInspectionComplete__c, Program_level__c,
                                    PreferredExempt__c, Account_Status__c, 
                                    Active_IAs__c, Last_Training__c
                            from Account where id IN :testme];

        Contactlists = [select   id, Account__c
                            from PreferredContact__c where Account__c IN :testme];

        for(PreferredIA__c q:tobeclosed) {
            q.Status__c = 'Closed'; 
        }

        for(Account z:invoicedaccounts) {
            /****************************************************************
                The following condition is where I am trying to set the z.EligibleIAs__c 
                which is a roll up count field of PreferredIA__c objects associated with 
                the account.
            ****************************************************************/
            if(z.EligibleIAs__c == 0
                && z.Program_Level__c == 'Preferred'
                && !z.PreferredExempt__c
                && (z.Account_Status__c == 'Active'
                    || z.Account_Status__c == 'Product Only')) {

                loopadd = new PreferredIA__c();
                system.debug(z.id);
                system.debug(z.Account_Status__c);
                loopadd.Account__c = z.id;

                if(z.PreferredOverride__c != null) {
                    loopadd.Specialist__c = z.PreferredOverride__c;
                }
                else {
                    loopadd.Specialist__c= z.Preferred_territory__r.Rep__c;
                }

                for(PreferredContact__c q:contactlists) {
                    if(q.Account__c == z.id) {
                        loopadd.PreferredContact__c = q.id;
                    }
                }

                loopadd.CreatedDate__c = Date.Today();
                if(z.Last_training__c != null) {
                    loopadd.DueDate__c = z.Last_Training__c.AddDays(365);
                }
                else {
                    loopadd.DueDate__c = Date.Today().AddDays(365);
                }
                loopadd.initial__c = false;
                loopadd.Status__c = 'Unacknowledged';
                newPreIAs.add(loopadd);
            }
            z.InitialInspectionComplete__c = true;
        }

        try {
            update tobeclosed;
            update invoicedaccounts;
            insert newPreIAs;
        }
        catch(system.dmlexception q) {
            system.debug(q);
            system.debug(invoicedaccounts);
            system.debug(newPreIAs);
        }
    }

    public void ReceivePPW() {
        monkey = [select id, Status__c from PreferredIA__c
                    where id in :preferredias and status__c = 'Training Completed'];

        for (PreferredIA__c m:monkey) {
            m.status__c = 'Awaiting Invoice';
        }

        update monkey;  
    }
}
```

Comment: The code example provided is not a test class, it appears to be a VF extension unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I can't actually see where you're trying to write to the field — or did you remove it because it wasn't working?

That aside, the answer is that you can not write to a roll-up summary field. If you require a value in that field you should insert child records to your parent test records, with appropriate field values such that your summary field calculates a value.

Also, I can see that you're querying PerferredIA__c at the start, your test methods should never depend on data being in the system already, you should insert your records yourself in your test code. The reason for this is that if you try to deploy to an org which has no relevant data, your tests will fail and so, subsequently, will your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

For situations like these, consider [mock objects (or just variables simulating expected values)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), similar to inserting test values as Lacey suggests. This technique is required to achieve 100% coverage when doing callouts, for example, since they terminate tests at the moment of the call.